# D3JS Petals / Flower Chart. How to adapt to use data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to adapt the "Animated Flowers" block by Jeremy Stucki

http://bl.ocks.org/herrstucki/6199768/23f51b97bd942f6b1b7cf0b9ba76ada4cb6d1cc7

to create a single, non-animated flower that is based on data that I supply for the size of each petal.

I create a single flower using data generated by the script in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/f91ujcfp/

The number of petals should be based on the number of rows in the supplied data (myPetalData) - that should be relatively easy.

```
var myPetalData = [
 {id:0, size:1, petLen:1, petWid:0.25},
 {id:1, size:2, petLen:1, petWid:0.5},
 {id:2, size:2.5, petLen:1, petWid:0.6},
 {id:3, size:5, petLen:1, petWid:1.0}
]
```

My main problem is in how to supply the data to the building of the individual petals (I am still learning Javascript and D3).
The petals could either be based on the 'size' variable specified in myPetalsData, or ideally a combination of the length and width variables petLen, petWid.  Size or Len+Wid should be coded to D3Scales to accomodate real-world data. I would also prefer to remove the grid dependency unless it is needed for petal construction.

This should be an easy one for someone with a basic grasp of Javascript and D3. I'd appreciate any advice or an updated fiddle to get me going along the correct path.

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: Anyone? Bueller??  I get it that this plot can be seen as a glorified(?) pie chart, but it would help me learn more D3 and JS, so I am hoping for some advice on this one. My goal is a chart showing the amount of contribution from multiple sources to a project. Size of the petal will be the amount of contribution relative to all sources, with colour being the 'type' of the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like

```js
var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    halfRadius = 50;  // length of petal & therefore size of digram overall

var size = d3.scale.sqrt()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([0, halfRadius]);

var myPetalData = [
 {id:0, size:1},
 {id:1, size:2},
 {id:2, size:2.5},
 {id:3, size:.1}
]

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

var petal = svg.selectAll(".petal")
  .data(pie(myPetalData))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "petal")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return r((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2); })
  .attr("d", petalPath)
  .style("stroke", petalStroke)
  .style("fill", petalFill);

function petalPath(d) {
  var angle = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2,
      s = polarToCartesian(-angle, halfRadius),
      e = polarToCartesian(angle, halfRadius),
      r = size(d.data.size),
      m = {x: halfRadius + r, y: 0},
      c1 = {x: halfRadius + r / 2, y: s.y},
      c2 = {x: halfRadius + r / 2, y: e.y};
  return "M0,0L" + s.x + "," + s.y + "Q" + c1.x + "," + c1.y + " " + m.x + "," + m.y + "L" + m.x + "," + m.y + "Q" + c2.x + "," + c2.y + " " + e.x + "," + e.y + "Z";
};

function petalFill(d, i) {
  return d3.hcl(i / myPetalData.length * 360, 60, 70);
};

function petalStroke(d, i) {
  return d3.hcl(i / myPetalData.length * 360, 60, 40);
};

function r(angle) {
  return "rotate(" + (angle / Math.PI * 180) + ")";
}

function polarToCartesian(angle, radius) {
  return {
    x: Math.cos(angle) * radius,
    y: Math.sin(angle) * radius
  };
};
```

note that I centered the pie and I removed petLen/petWid as it's not clear to me how you expect these to relate to the petal size ...

Comment: This fits what I was looking for in an answer. Thank you very much.  I don't know what I was thinking about petal petLen/petWid, since Size does what I want. I've applied a D3 scale to my actual data and it looks good. Cheers!